# SQL Server transaction handling

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I'm running the following stored procedure and I'm receiving the error

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

what am I missing here?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spImportData
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY 
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType ON
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'IDENTITY_INSERT IS ON'
END CATCH
GO

BEGIN TRY
   INSERT INTO PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType(ActionTypeID,ActionType,ActionTypeDescription)
      SELECT ActionTypeID,ActionType,ActionTypeDescription 
      FROM PINCDOCControlOld..tblActionType

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType OFF
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType OFF
   EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea ON
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'IDENTITY_INSERT IS ON'
END CATCH

GO

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea(AreaID,AreaDescription,AreaNo)
        SELECT AreaNo,AreaDescription,Area 
        FROM PINCDOCControlOld..tblArea

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea OFF
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea OFF
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo
END CATCH

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    -- Rollback the transaction
    ROLLBACK

    -- Raise an error and return
    RAISERROR ('Error in inserting.', 16, 1)
    RETURN
 END
 COMMIT
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down your statement a little? That's a lot of stuff that could potentially be interfering. I'd suggest removing some of the contents a little bit at a time, until you've got a smaller sample. Then maybe it would be easier to see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: I suggest you read about [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) and what it is used for. It shouldn't exist within a stored procedure.

Comment: @Oded: agree. OP hasn't checked the state of spImportData where they'd see what is wrong

Comment: I would try to have **one** `BEGIN TRY` ..... `END TRY`  and put all your *real* code inside this try block, and put any error handling in the `BEGIN CATCH` block. The last statement in the TRY block is the COMMIT, and in your CATCH block you have a ROLLBACK.... this "micro-error handling" of yours, intermixed with checkign the @@ERROR variable, just doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: BTW: Trying to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on multiple times for the same table does not raise an error. You would only get the error if `IDENTITY_INSERT` was already on for another table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try to have just a single `BEGIN TRY .... END TRY` block, in which you have all your logic that you want to execute. If anything goes wrong - anywhere in your logic - you'll be thrown into the `BEGIN CATCH.... END CATCH` block.

Start your transaction before your `BEGIN TRY`, and have the only `COMMIT` as the last statement in your `TRY` block - and in your `CATCH` block, have a rollback.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spImportData
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY 
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType ON

        INSERT INTO 
            PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType(ActionTypeID, ActionType, ActionTypeDescription)
            SELECT 
               ActionTypeID, ActionType, ActionTypeDescription 
            FROM 
              PINCDOCControlOld..tblActionType

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType OFF

        -- tblArea
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea ON

        INSERT INTO 
             PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea(AreaID, AreaDescription, AreaNo)
           SELECT 
               AreaNo, AreaDescription, Area 
           FROM 
               PINCDOCControlOld..tblArea

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea OFF

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

       SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblActionType OFF
       SET IDENTITY_INSERT PINCDOCControlNew..tblArea OFF

       EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo

       RAISERROR ('Error in inserting.', 16, 1)
    END CATCH
```

With this approach, you have **exactly ONE** `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, and either one single corresponding `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, or a single corresponding `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

I typically also add this `SELECT` statement to my `CATCH` block to get the error message and error code of what went wrong:

```
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
```

Answer (score 7):

> what am i missing here?

You probably have a surplus rather than a deficit. You need to remove the `GO` statements.

The only sensible interpretation of your script is that it is all intended to be part of the `spImportData` stored procedure definition.

This ends at the first `GO` statement (used by client tools to delimit batches) and the remaining batches are **executed immediately** in auto commit transactions as no explicit `BEGIN TRAN` has been run. When the `COMMIT` statement is reached there is nothing to commit hence the error.